# Injectives realized as limits in some appropriate category

Tags: category-theory, injective-module, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

[Injective obects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_object) behave a lot like limits. For instance:

- The limit of an injective is an injective.
- If a left adjoint preserves monomorphisms, then the right adjoint preserves injectives.

Given this, is it possible to define an injective as a limit, perhaps in some suitable comma category?

Comment: Injectives are like [weak limits](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+limit), not limits, because the maps that they require to exist are not unique.

Comment: It is not true that limits of injective objects are injective. Products and retracts, yes, but not equalisers.